# couchdb 2.0 installation error

Tags: installation, couchdb, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to install couchdb2.0 on ubuntu server 14.04 following these guides:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/unix.html
https://gist.github.com/SinanGabel/eac83a2f9d0ac64e2c9d4bd936be9313#file-couchdb-2-0-install-L33
the process starts but it keeps giving the following errors:

```
couchdb@outland:/opt/couchdb/bin$ (./couchdb &)
couchdb@outland:/opt/couchdb/bin$ [info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.870856Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_log started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.874078Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application folsom started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.901209Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_stats started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.901354Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application khash started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.907365Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_event started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.911510Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application ibrowse started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.915353Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application ioq started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.915495Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application mochiweb started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.915630Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application oauth started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.921324Z couchdb@localhost <0.208.0> -------- Apache CouchDB 2.0.0 is starting.

[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:35.921380Z couchdb@localhost <0.209.0> -------- Starting couch_sup
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.213900Z couchdb@localhost <0.208.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.

[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.214019Z couchdb@localhost <0.208.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started on http://127.0.0.1:5986/
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.214177Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.214321Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application ets_lru started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.223976Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application rexi started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.281819Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application mem3 started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.281978Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application fabric started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.302058Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application chttpd started on node couchdb@localhost
[notice] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.319236Z couchdb@localhost <0.323.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.319444Z couchdb@localhost emulator -------- Error in process <0.324.0> on node couchdb@localhost with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}

[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.323075Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_index started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.323153Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_mrview started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.323185Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_plugins started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.359313Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_replicator started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.359344Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application couch_peruser started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.364479Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application ddoc_cache started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.378800Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application global_changes started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.379083Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application jiffy started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.383212Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application mango started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.389163Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application setup started on node couchdb@localhost
[info] 2017-01-09T17:26:36.389210Z couchdb@localhost <0.9.0> -------- Application snappy started on node couchdb@localhost
[notice] 2017-01-09T17:26:41.319862Z couchdb@localhost <0.323.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-01-09T17:26:41.320369Z couchdb@localhost emulator -------- Error in process <0.450.0> on node couchdb@localhost with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
```

I don't think it's normal but I don't know what to do and what does it means.
someone knows?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into similar issues and executed the following commands on the same host couchdb is running on , found the information here

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/index.html

Under single node setup

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_users

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicator

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_global_changes
```

Comment: when I do this I get a you are not authorized and I have yet to even get started

Comment: @Chris try specifying the admin username and password in your command like this: 
curl -X PUT http://admin_name:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_users

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `curl`, the Fauxton CouchDB user interface includes a Setup section which will create these databases for you.